# doctl is unable to find docker binary

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, snapcraft, container-registry

**Configuring Digital Ocean Container Registry**

link : https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/how-to/set-up-registry/

> After Successfully : Snap install doctl

```
#doctl regitry login
Error : unable to Find Docker binary . make sure docker is installed 

#docker --version 
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
```

Github Issue : https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/issues/709

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Problem**

**doctl** is not able to find docker because snap binary path is /usr/snap/bin 
and docker binary path is /usr/local/bin/

so somehow connection between them is broken

> THIS IS MY CUSTOM **SOLUTION** TO MAKE IT WORK :

**Step-1 :  Uninstall doctl  and Refresh env path**

`#sudo snap remove doctl`

**Step-2 : Install doctl using latest package**

```
wget https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/download/v1.17.0/doctl-1.17.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
curl -sL https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/download/v1.38.0/doctl-1.38.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar -xzv
sudo mv ~/doctl /usr/local/bin
```

**(optional)Step ? : Fix path Problem**
*if doctl not found then fix it using Symbolic Link*

`ln -s  /usr/local/bin/doctl /usr/snap/doctl`

**Step-3 : Run docker login command**

`#doctl registry login`

> **IF getting error related to x11 then run command below and try Step-3 **

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt -V install gnupg2 pass
```

`#doctl registry login`

`login successfully`